# vs2010. Call Hierarchy. Is there a way to generate call hierarchy for all methods at once?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I've found `View Call Hierarchy` helpful in making sense of new code. Can it be automated ?Now, I'm clicking on every method and hitting (Ctrl+K,Ctr+T). Is it possible to generate Call Hierarchy for a class? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

There are some fantastic 3rd party applications out there. [nDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) is a sophisticated tool that maps out your assemblies and generates all sorts of metrics on your code. It also does some interesting things like comparing your assemblies with previous builds to determine when/if you break public APIs.

[Here](http://www.ndepend.com/docs/visual-studio-dependency-graph#Call) are explanations about how to generate call hierarchy for all methods at once with NDepend.

If you're more interested in a look at the call hierarchy during runtime, so far I've been a really big fan of [ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/). You can profile your code for a span of time, then drill into code that was running at a certain point in time, and then generate an exportable call graph which displays the percentage of time spent in each method. It's awesome.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really the direct answer to your question, because I think you want to see the call hierarchy when not in runtime. But there is a nice, cool new extension for visual studio which gives you a great overview about what is calling what in runtime => Debugger Canvas

You can get it from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/hh227299

Comment: needs to have VS2010 Ultimate... boohoo.